# ASP.net trying to print variable value on page

Tags: asp.net, html, variables

My source is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css?v=<%=Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jgrowl.css?v=<%=Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER %>" />
```

This renders as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css?v=&lt;%=Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jgrowl.css?v=&lt;%=Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER %>" />
```

If I print the value in the body, it prints fine:

```
1
```

Anyone know why this is, and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=String.Concat(""css/default.css?v="" ,Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER) %>" />
```

Or putting runat serever in the head

```
<head runat="Server">
```

Comment: Works great, thanks.  Why does my example not work though?  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't tell you why, but in my experience ASP.NET needs the whole attribute to have magic quotes, or it just treats it as HTML. PS - I do this exact same technique in my pages to force a refresh on CSS!

Comment: Actually they are known as "Code Render Blocks". Use <%= for HTML and <%# for server controls, and generally fill the whole attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You need use this in form with runat attribute:

```
<form runat=server>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css?v=
 <%=Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jgrowl.css?v=
 <%=Config.CSS_VERSION_NUMBER %>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Only 1 form tag allowed per page, and I don't think this error has anything to do with that either I'm afraid :-(